# What HTML5 Canvas tools should I use to build a card game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-canvas, game-engine

I'm looking to create a card game using HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript, and I want to know what Canvas tools could make my life easier.

I've found [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com) and taken some notes on it:

- Suite of libraries/tools for simplifying complex interactions with HTML5/CSS/JS

  - [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) - Abstraction layer on top of HTML5 Canvas
  - [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) - Abstraction layer for HTML5 Audio
  - [TweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS) - Library for animating HTML5 and CSS properties (cool easing demo)
  - [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS) - Library for preloading assets (JS, images, sounds, data, etc.)
- [Documentation](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/) seems thorough
- [Lots of demos](http://www.createjs.com/#demos); no Getting Started Guide/Tutorial to be found
- Free and [open-source](https://github.com/CreateJS/) (sponsored by Adobe and Microsoft)

What other tools/engines would be useful for making card games for the browser?

Bonus points for tools/frameworks that would help me outside of HTML5 Canvas. I'm using Node.js on the backend, and planning on using Socket.IO/Express/MongoDB, since that's what I know.

Note: I've collected some notes on game engines/tools (including the CreateJS notes above) in [this Google Doc](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/). Feel free to add your points to this doc.

Comment: +1 for use `Node.js` in a context that make sense ;)

Comment: Having worked with `Node.js` for just over a year, I can vouch for the truth in the "law of the instrument": "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to check this [list](https://gist.github.com/bebraw/768272), but seems like you are missing a couple of sprite based canvas libraries:

- [GameJS](http://gamejs.org)
- [Doodle-js](http://lamberta.org/doodle-js)

Also I can recommend [jaws](https://github.com/ippa/jaws), because I have used in an online casino game (bingo) with good results. They described as:

> Easy and robust game state system to switch between menus, play, high score lists and settings